# SQL: Usage of count() - Confusion and explanation

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, select, count

I am working with the following database tables in SQL (the entries are just examples):

One table to hold information about a **film**:

```
****************** film ******************
filmid (int)    |   title (string)              | prodyear (int)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2919898         | Devil May Cry                     | 2011
7246970         | Three Men Seeking Monsters        | 2010
```

One table to hold information about **film participation**:

```
****************** filmparticipation ******************
partid (int)    | personid (int) | filmid (int) | parttype (string)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
17              | 17             | 52               | costume designer
85              | 70             | 69               | director`enter code here`
```

And one table to hold information about a **person**:

```
****************** person ******************
personid (int)  | lastname (string) | firstname (string)    | gender (char)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
167076          | Jones             | Anthony               | M
197             | Mitchell          | Julia                 | F
```

Now for the **QUESTION**:

1) I have tried writing a query for **Finding the names and total number of movies a person has participated in. My query looks like the following:

```
select 
    p.lastname, p.firstname, count(distinct f.filmid) as numberOfMovies
from
    film f, filmparticipation x, person p
where
    x.filmid = f.filmid and
    x.personid = p.personid
group by 
    p.lastname, p.firstname
```

I believe I am having problems with **count()**, as it returns 1 for every tuple.

2) A similar query, **Get the filmid, number of people involved and production year (prodyear) for all movies directed by Christopher Nolan**. My query is as follows:

```
select
    f.title, f.filmid, count (distinct x.partid), prodyear
from
    film f, filmparticipation x, person p, filmparticipationinfo inf
where
    p.firstname='Christopher' and
    p.lastname='Nolan' and
    x.personid = p.personid and
    x.parttype = 'director' and
    x.filmid = f.filmid
group by
    f.title, f.filmid, prodyear
order by
    prodyear asc;
```

Again, in the result, **count()** is set as 1 for every movie, which is incorrect.

If anyone could explain how to properly use **count()**, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First, You should learm more about JOINs. Second, to get the correct count that would need to be a sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Using JOINs, sub-query to get the correct counts, your queries should be:

**a) Finding the names and total number of movies a person has participated in**

```
SELECT 
    p.lastname,
    p.firstname,
    (SELECT COUNT(filmid) FROM filmparticipation WHERE personid = p.personid) AS numberOfMovies
FROM
    person p
GROUP BY
    p.lastname, p.firstname
```

**b) Get the filmid, number of people involved and production year (prodyear) for all movies directed by Christopher Nolan**

```
SELECT
    f.title,
    f.filmid,
    (SELECT COUNT(partid) FROM filmparticipation WHERE filmid = f.filmid) AS numberOfPeople,
    f.prodyear
FROM
    film f
LEFT JOIN filmparticipation x ON f.filmid = x.filmid
LEFT JOIN person p ON x.personid = p.personid
WHERE
    p.firstname = 'Christopher'
    AND p.lastname='Nolan'
    AND x.parttype = 'director'
GROUP BY
    f.title, f.filmid, f.prodyear
ORDER BY
    f.prodyear ASC;
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x...  - a bit confused?

Comment: A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN in combination with a WHERE clause (acting on the same table) translates as an [INNER] JOIN.

Comment: I thought only `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x IS NOT NULL` translates into INNER JOIN... Hmm, can you point to docu?

Comment: Why not just test it yourself? A simple EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by show warnings should suffice

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
select
    p.lastname, p.firstname, count(DISTINCT x.filmid) as numberOfMovies
from
    film f, filmparticipation x, person p
where
    x.personid = p.personid
     and
    x.filmid = f.filmid
group by
    p.lastname, p.firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. The first case is simple and you can use JOIN with count() to get the result. In the 2nd case its a bit complicated

```
select
p.personid,
p.lastname,
p.firstname,
count(distinct fp.filmid) as numberOfMovies
from person p
join filmparticipation fp on fp.personid = p.personid
join film f on f.filmid = fp.filmid
group by p.personid;



select
f.filmid,
f.title,
f.prodyear,
count(*) as total
from film f
join (
  select filmid from filmparticipation fp
  join person p on p.personid = fp.personid
  where p.lastname = 'Christopher' AND p.firstname= 'Nolan' AND fp.parttype = 'director'
)x
on x.filmid = f.filmid
join filmparticipation fp1 on fp1.filmid = f.filmid
group by f.filmid
```

Check the **[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff88ac/4)** here